# a PHP table map

Tags: php, html, css

I want to create a game where I have to create a map with PHP. I want to create 100 tables boxes in the right way but I can't get it work...

```
$field = 100;
echo "<table border='3px' dir='ltr'>";
for ($row=0; $row < 10 ; $row++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($column=0; $column < 10; $column++) {
    echo "<td>";
      echo $field;
      $field--;
    echo "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
 echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

This gives me this table:
[image: Table Image]

But I will need a table like:
[image: What I need]

Comment: What have you tried to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 2):

If a for loop is not a requirement.

I would use an array, then you have a set to work from rather then calculating things, then you just need reverse the odd row, like so:

```
$rows = array_reverse(array_chunk(range(1, 100), 10));

echo "<table>\n";
foreach ($rows as $level => $row) {
  if (($level-1) % 2) {
    $row = array_reverse($row);
  }
  echo "\t<tr>\n";
  foreach ($row as $value) {
    echo "\t\t<td>$value</td>\n"; 
  }
  echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "<table>\n";
```

https://3v4l.org/204eh

Comment: Good answer. My only comment would be to make the chunk value (10) a square root of the total value so that the board can be any square size (144, 256, etc.) `array_chunk(range(1, 100), sqrt($field));`

Comment: Yeah, like: https://3v4l.org/jBnQ9 ? though its beyond the scope of the question so won't change it.